# bash script: send command within command

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I want to create a bash script that would connect to a server and run jupyter notebook on that server.

How do I run jupyter notebook command while I am connected to the server using bash script?

I use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@999.99.99.999 
jupyter notebook --port 9999
```

When I run the script I get connected to the server using `ssh dave@999.99.99.999`command but the `jupyter notebook --port 9999` command runs only after I manually close the connection to server.

How do I run `jupyter notebook --port 9999` after I am connected to the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just write command you want to run on the remote server as follows :

```
ssh user@999.99.99.999 'jupyter notebook --port 9999'
```

You can use the following formats to run command using ssh on remote server

```
ssh user1@server1 command1
ssh user1@server1 'command2'
ssh user1@server1 'command1 | command2'
```